# Count elements in recursive list

Tags: r, list

How can I count elements in recursive list?
Here is data, but it could be bigger list.

```
data <- list(list(list("a"), list("b"), list("c","d","e")), list("f"))

> str(data)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "b"
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : chr "c"
  .. ..$ : chr "d"
  .. ..$ : chr "e"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : chr "f"
```

On output I want to have vector with % usage which sums to 100%:

```
o <- c(1/2/3/1, 1/2/3/1, 1/2/3/3, 1/2/3/3, 1/2/3/3, 1/2/1)
[1] 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.50000000
sum(o)
[1] 1
```

So I need v1 (is just rep of allocation = 100%):

```
v1 <- rep(1, length( unlist(data) ))
v1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

v2:

```
> v2 <- rep(length(data), length( unlist(data) ))
> v2
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

v3,

```
> v3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1)
```

v4:

> v4 = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1)

etc.

In result:

```
> v1/v2/v3/v4
[1] 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.50000000
sum(v1/v2/v3/v4)
[1] 1
```

So question is how I can make v3 and v4 etc. ?

Maybe is there way to get vector of str(data) count length of each child like:

```
out <- c("2/3/1", "2/3/1", "2/3/3", "2/3/3", "2/3/3", "2/1")
```

Then with this vector I can do math:

```
> sapply(out, function(x) last(cumprod(1 / c(1, as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")))))))
     2/3/1      2/3/1      2/3/3      2/3/3      2/3/3        2/1 
0.16666667 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.50000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lends itself to a recursive solution, possibly something like:

```
data <- list(list(list("a"), list("b"), list("c","d","e")), list("f"))


f <- function(x, prop=1)
{
  if(is.list(x)) lapply(x, f, prop=prop/length(x))
  else prop/length(x)
}

unlist(f(data))

#[1] 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.50000000
```