# R Turning list characters into other lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I can't reproduce my data so I'll provide sampel data that is similar:

```
lst1 <- list(IT = c("Training", "Helpdesk"), Construction = c("Water", "Waste"))
lst2 <- list(Training = c("Alarm Engineer", "Backend Engineer"),
             Helpdesk = c("Analyst 1", "Analyst 2"),
             Water = c("Water 1", "Water 2"),
             Waste = c("Waste 1", "Waste 2", "Waste 3"))
lst3 <- list(`Alarm Engineer` = head(mtcars), `Backend Engineer` = head(VADeaths),
             `Analyst 1` = head(diamonds), `Analyst 2` = head(ChickWeight),
             `Water 1` = head(state.x77), `Water 2` = head(iris),
             `Waste 1` = head(CO2), `Waste 2` = head(cbind(letters, LETTERS)),
             `Waste 3` = state.abb)
```

First (lst1) I have small nested list of length 35:

```
head(dis_sub, 2)         
$IT
 [1] "Web Developer"         "Web Designer"          "Training"              "Testing"               "Technician"            "Technical Support"    
 [7] "Systems Engineer"      "Systems Analyst"       "Helpdesk"     

$Construction

 [1] "Water"                     "Waste"                     "Sustainability"            "Structural Engineer"       "Skilled Trades"           
 [6] "Site Manager"              "Mechanical and Electrical"
```

Then I have a second nested list of length 250 (lst2):

```
head(sub_jobs, 2)
$Mechanical and Electrical

    [1] "Alarm Engineer"          "Backend Engineer"     "Biomass Engineer"                         
  [4] "Building Engineer"         "Cam Engineer"       "Electrician" 

$Helpdesk

 [1] "1st Line Analyst"                 "1st Line Desktop Support Analyst" "1st Line Engineer"                "1st Line Helpdesk"               
 [5] "1st Line Helpdesk Support"    "1st Line IT Support"    "1st Line IT
```

Then I have a final list (lst3), this list is a list of data frames all with one common variable but with sifferent numbers of observations:

```
   head(list_all, 2)
$Electrician
                              words
1                     17th edition 
2       17th edition qualification 
3           17th edition qualified 
4                          3 phase 
5                     access point 

$1st Line Helpdesk Support
                                        words
1                 1st line technical support 
2                      2nd line support team 
3                 2nd line technical support
```

Now you may have spotted that in the first list, under IT we see Helpdesk. And under Construction, we see Mechanical and Electrical

I want to turn these from characters, into the lists in list two.

Then from there we see in list two under Mechanical and Electrical we have Electricianand under Helpdesk we see 1st Line Helpdesk Support. I'd then want those characters to be turned into the data.frames in list 3.

It may have been stupid of me the make the lists I made and go from there. I can obviously make simple lists of 35 and 250 and I do also have a data frame like:

```
dis           sub       norm
IT            Helpdesk  1st Line Helpdesk Support
IT            Helpdesk  Analyst
IT            Testing   Tester
Construction  Mech...   Electrician 
Construction  Mech..    Alarm Engineer 
Construction  Waste     Recycling Engineer
```

And then a folder full of csv's that are each named after each norm row above and contain data.frames which were used to make the list of data.frames in list 3.

What I would like is:

```
>List
$IT
   Helpdesk
            1st Line Helpdesk Support
                    1                 1st line technical support 
                    2                      2nd line support team 
                    3                 2nd line technical support
                    ...
            Analyst
                    ...
            ...
   Web developer
            ...
                    ...
   ...

$Construction
             Mechanical and Electrical
                             Electrician
                                     1                     17th edition 
                                     2       17th edition qualification 
                                     3           17th edition qualified
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this is receiving negative votes? I thought I was clear and have presented examples of my data for others to replicate?

Comment: Try `lapply(dis_sub, function(x) lapply(sub_jobs[x], function(.x) list_all[.x]))`

Comment: It does work. I can show you.

Comment: That is because your names are not exactly matching. For example you have `Mechanical & Electrical` in one list and `Mechanical and Electrical` in another.

Comment: Youre right, I apologize, I didnt remove whitespace in list_all so names in that list wouldnt match dis_sub and sub_jobs which explains my null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can nest a subset.

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) lapply(lst2[x], function(.x) lst3[.x]))
```

**Data**

```
lst1 <- list(IT = c("Training", "Helpdesk"), Construction = c("Water", "Waste"))
lst2 <- list(Training = c("Alarm Engineer", "Backend Engineer"),
             Helpdesk = c("Analyst 1", "Analyst 2"),
             Water = c("Water 1", "Water 2"),
             Waste = c("Waste 1", "Waste 2", "Waste 3"))
lst3 <- list(`Alarm Engineer` = head(mtcars), `Backend Engineer` = head(VADeaths),
             `Analyst 1` = head(diamonds), `Analyst 2` = head(ChickWeight),
             `Water 1` = head(state.x77), `Water 2` = head(iris),
             `Waste 1` = head(CO2), `Waste 2` = head(cbind(letters, LETTERS)),
             `Waste 3` = state.abb)
```

**Output**

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) lapply(lst2[x], function(.x) lst3[.x]))
$IT
$IT$Training
$IT$Training$`Alarm Engineer`
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

$IT$Training$`Backend Engineer`
      Rural Male Rural Female Urban Male Urban Female
50-54       11.7          8.7       15.4          8.4
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0


$IT$Helpdesk
$IT$Helpdesk$`Analyst 1`
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl>     <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48

$IT$Helpdesk$`Analyst 2`
  weight Time Chick Diet
1     42    0     1    1
2     51    2     1    1
3     59    4     1    1
4     64    6     1    1
5     76    8     1    1
6     93   10     1    1
```

Comment: is .x the same as i or y  (any dummy) or does it have some relation to x from the higher level loop?

Comment: It is arbitrary and isn't connected to anything else. Just a made-up name

Comment: also what part of my question is bad, I dont want negative votes and will edit it

Comment: I don't know why they voted it down. Maybe add `dput(head(sub_jobs))` and the other lists so that someone can cut and paste the data easily to try out different solutions.

Comment: quick q, how do I skip levels. For example TEST$Retail$`Project Manager`[1]    gives me Agile project manager along with its dataframe and TEST$Retail$`Project Manager`[[1]] returns just the dataframe. If I wanted to work backwards and pull all the words from all the data frames is there a simple way to like: for(i in TEST$*$*[[i]]){print(i)}

Comment: The single brackets will return a list, the double brackets will return the contents of the list. I'm not sure what you asking exactly.

Comment: Ill explain with a simpler example. Imagine I have a list with a and b. a is another list with 1 2 3, b has  1 2 3 as well. Then each number is a random word. If I wanted to look at all words, irrespective of what number or if its in a or b, how do I go straight to that deepest level for all results.

Comment: Here is a function for recursive list searches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624384/count-elements-in-recursive-list